# Preventing duplicates from being added to a Custom Adapter and database

Tags: android, listview, adapter, hashset

I have been searching for a solution and only coming across HashSet and I am having trouble implementing it.  Most explanations are vague making it difficult for me to understand it and implement it withing my example. I would like to use HashSet or an equal efficient solution.  I have not worked with HashSet's so if someone can explain how to implement with my code and explain how it works or another solution.  If you need more code or don't understand my question I will update my answer.

**Adapter**

```
public class LogSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LogSearch> {
    private static LogSearchAdapter instance;
    Context mContext;
    public static List<LogSearch> mLogs;

    public LogSearchAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<LogSearch> logs) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        mLogs = logs;
    }

    public void setLogs(List<LogSearch> logs) {
        mLogs = logs;
    }

    public List<LogSearch> getLogs() {
        return mLogs;
    }

    public void add(LogSearch log) {
        mLogs.add(log);
    }

    public void remove(LogSearch log) {
        LogSearchAdapter.mLogs.remove(log);
    }

    public static LogSearchAdapter getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LogSearchAdapter(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 4, mLogs);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mLogs.size();
    }

    public LogSearch getItem(int position) {
        return mLogs.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LogSearchRow view = (LogSearchRow) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new LogSearchRow(mContext);
        }
        LogSearch log = getItem(position);
        view.setLog(log);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
listSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSearch);
logSearchAdapter = new LogSearchAdapter(this, 0, LogSearch.all());
listSearch.setAdapter(logSearchAdapter);


etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            search();
            // Saving items to the Database
            LogSearch LogSearch = new LogSearch();
            LogSearch.setName(etSearch.getText().toString());
            LogSearch.save();
            // Adding the saved item to the Adapter
            logSearchAdapter.add(LogSearch);
            logSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //  listSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Working Solution**  Credit to  Pramod Yadav

```
etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
listSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSearch);
Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
logSearchAdapter = new LogSearchAdapter(this, 0, LogSearch.all());
listSearch.setAdapter(logSearchAdapter);


etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            // search();
            // Adding the names from the adapter to to the Set
            for (int i = 0; i < logSearchAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                LogSearch ls = logSearchAdapter.getItem(i);
                set.add(ls.getName());
            }
            if (set.add(etSearch.getText().toString())) {
                // Saving items to the Database
                LogSearch LogSearch = new LogSearch();
                LogSearch.setName(etSearch.getText().toString());
                LogSearch.save();
                // Adding the saved item to the Adapter
                logSearchAdapter.add(LogSearch);
                logSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                //do whatever you want to do for duplicate values
            }
            // listSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: you don't want duplicate values in your logsearch class right

Comment: @PramodYadav Yes that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is create a hashmap and track that there is no duplicate value

```
etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
listSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSearch);
Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
logSearchAdapter = new LogSearchAdapter(this, 0, LogSearch.all());
listSearch.setAdapter(logSearchAdapter);


etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        search();
        // Saving items to the Database
        if(set.add(etSearch.getText().toString()))
       {
        LogSearch LogSearch = new LogSearch();
        LogSearch.setName(etSearch.getText().toString());
        LogSearch.save();
        // Adding the saved item to the Adapter
        logSearchAdapter.add(LogSearch);
        logSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
      else
       {
           //do whatever you want to do for duplicate values
         }
        //  listSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
 });
```

as you will store the value evertime in hashset as if the hashset do not contain the value then set.add() method will return true and the value will be added to the hashset and if the value is already present in the hashset then it will return false,hope it will clarify things

Comment: How would I attach the Set to the adapter?  It works only if you search the same thing in a single lifecyle.  I am trying to prevent duplicates every time a user searches.

Comment: i have implemented this on your onEditorActionListener so if the value will be a duplicate then the LogSearch object won't be created and added to the list and notifydatasetchanged() won't be called if it is not a duplicate value then everything will proceed as you coded have you implemented the code

Comment: I got it to work with this;   for (int i = 0; i < logSearchAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        LogSearch ls = logSearchAdapter.getItem(i);
                        set.add(ls.getName());
                    }

Comment: I called the loop statement to add all the names then implemented what you said to do and it worked.  If you want to update your answer with my previous comment I believe it can help people if they have the same issue.